# 完全二分木は森に分類されますか？

Tags: アルゴリズム

どういった場合が森に分類されるのですか？

Answer (score 11):

[Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%A8_(%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6))によれば、木と森の定義は以下の通りです。

木: 連結で閉路を持たない無向グラフ
森: 閉路を持たない無向グラフ

森の特殊な形が木なので、すべての木は森です。完全二分木も、もちろん森です。

いくつか例を挙げます。xが節で-と|が枝だと思ってください。

```
    x---x
    |
x---x---x
    |
    x---x
```

これは**木**であり、**森**でもあります。

```
    x---x
    |   |
x---x---x
    |
    x---x
```

これは閉路があるので**木**でもなく、**森**でもありません。

```
    x---x         x
    |             |
x---x---x    x----x----x
    |                
    x---x
```

これは連結していないので**木**ではありませんが、**森**です。
（2つの連結しているグラフを個別に見れば**木・森**です）

```
    x---x         x
    |   |         |
x---x---x    x----x----x
    |                
    x---x
```

これは閉路があって連結もしていないので**木**でもなく、**森**でもありません。
（右のグラフだけを見れば**木・森**です）

```
    x---x        x
    |            |
x---x---x---x----x----x
    |                
    x---x
```

これは**木**であり、**森**でもあります。